# How to handling if subquery returns multiple value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure in which I'm using sub query, but the issue is that my sub query returns 2 values and I've to return all records based on these two values.

```
Select * from [Address] where AddressID=
(Select AddressID from PersonAddress where PersonID=
(select Claimant from [Case] where CaseID=35))
```

In this query AddressID returning two values and both the value having record in table, I've to return both the address.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `=` use `IN`:

```
Select * from [Address] where AddressID IN
(Select AddressID from PersonAddress where PersonID IN
(select Claimant from [Case] where CaseID=35))
```

or try `JOIN`, the correct way:

```
Select * from Address a
inner join PersonAddress p on a.AdressID = p.AddressID
inner join Case c on p.PersonID = c.Claimant
where c.CaseID = 35
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- use IN clause like this:

  Select * 
  from [Address] 
  where 
  AddressID IN 
    (
      Select AddressID 
      from PersonAddress 
      where PersonID IN (select Claimant from [Case] where CaseID=35)
    )
- or limit your subqueries with TOP clause

  Select * from [Address] where AddressID=
  (Select TOP 1 AddressID from PersonAddress where PersonID=
  (select TOP 1 Claimant from [Case] where CaseID=35))

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [Address]
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 
            NULL 
        from 
            PersonAddress
        WHERE
            PersonAddress.AddressID=[Address].AddressID
            AND EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT
                        NULL
                    FROM
                        [Case]
                    WHERE
                        [Case].CaseID=35
                        AND PersonAddress.PersonID=[Case].Claimant
                )
    )
```